# WPF datagrid bound to typed dataset. Highlight individual cells background colour based on a List<Point>

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf app that has a datagrid which is bound (MVVM) to a typed dataset.  The data displays (auto generated columns) just fine.

I also have a (in the ViewModel) List collection that represents the cells that have "bad" data in them.  I want to change the background colour for the individual cells in the datagrid that correspond to list of points.  I can not figure out how I can access each cell individually.

I tried a converter passing in the list of problems but realised I had no way of knowing which cell (X and Y) I was in at that time.

I have tried GridData_OnAutoGeneratedColumns event but can not figure out how to reference an individual cell.

I am flumaxed.

Thanks

Comment: Can this _'point'_ (which is in List<Point>) be part of your typed dataset (i.e. can each row of your dataset have a column named 'IsBad' with boolean value)? In that case you can probably bind the background with the boolean (using a converter).

Comment: @publicgk sadly it needs to be cell specific so marking the whole row is not an option.

Comment: so do the X,Y of your Point represent the x,y cell number in datagrid?

Comment: One more thing, how do you decide whether a cell has bad value or not? There must be separate logic for each column. e.g. if there are two columns, revenue and profit. The logic for revenue column coould be: if(revenue < 50000) then bad; and for profit column could be (if profit < 0) then bad. If you are having this logic and creating your list<point> based on this, why not have this logic in your convertors for each cell? Maybe if you post code, that will help making lesser assumptions. :)

Comment: the logic is pretty complex and is run via multiple processes / processors before hand.  This is not something I could or would put into the client / view.

Answer (score 1):

Saw your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665302/wpf-datagrid-find-single-cells-x-and-y-and-set-background-colour) on the same problem and thought of revisiting here.

Well, this should fit your needs: [Get cell value from WPF Datagrid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/74332b78-6bfd-4ac9-af85-dfd9bec87a29)

What you need to do is:

1. Find a specific time when to run the below logic. This should ideally be after your datagrid has been bound.

2. Iterate your `List<x,y>`.

3. For each item in your `List<x,y>`, make a call to the GetCell helper function in the referenced link and get access to the DataGridCell.

4. Change the color of DataGridCell or do whatever you want to do with it.

Be aware that:

1. You will need to figure out the appropritate time (step 1) to run the logic.

2. This solution is kind of against the MVVM. However, since you have a peculiar need, it should suffice.

3. The question in that link basically wants to get the value of DataGridCell. You however should be happy with the DataGridCell that is returned by that helper function, as you only want to change the background color and not the value.

4. The GetRow function code is not mentioned in that link. However, it refers to an article where you can download the code and see the GetRow method.

5. Virtualization is On by default for datagrid. Hence, the DataGridCells which are not shown on screen are not created. If you use the helper function as-it-is and your datagrid is huge, it may load very slowly, because the helper function tries to bring all the requested cells into view by scrolling to them. You may want to look into LoadingRow and UnloadingRow events of datagrid.

Comment: This helped me to go a different solution, (posted here). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem, (not sure if it is optimal but seems to work, (so far):

I have a multi value converter on the Style for the datagrid cell:

```
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
           <Style.Setters>
               <Setter Property="Background">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource onErrorConverter}">
                           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=SampleTests:SampleTestUserControlBase}" Path="DataContext.Problems" />
                           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" />
                       </MultiBinding>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter> 
           </Style.Setters>
      </Style>
```

And the converter:

```
public class DataGridCellOnErrorConversion : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private readonly SolidColorBrush DefaultColour = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    private readonly SolidColorBrush ErrorColour = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private readonly SolidColorBrush AlternatingColour = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);


    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 3)
            return DefaultColour;

        DataGridCell dgc = values[0] as DataGridCell;
        if(dgc == null)
            return DefaultColour;

        IList<Point> problems = values[1] as IList<Point>;
        if(problems == null)
            return DefaultColour;

        DataGrid grid = values[2] as DataGrid;
        if (grid == null)
            return DefaultColour;
        int x;
        int y = -1;

        ItemCollection itemCollection = grid.Items;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itemCollection.CurrentItem == itemCollection[i])
                y = i;
        }

        x = dgc.Column.DisplayIndex;

        DataRowView currentRowView = null;
        FieldInfo fi = dgc.GetType().GetField("_owner", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        try
        {
            if (fi != null)
            {
                DataGridRow dataGridRow = fi.GetValue(dgc) as DataGridRow;
                if(dataGridRow != null)
                    currentRowView = dataGridRow.Item as DataRowView;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException) { }

        if(currentRowView != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                if (currentRowView == itemCollection[i])
                    y = i;
            }
        }

        if (problems.Any(problem => System.Convert.ToInt32(problem.X) == x && System.Convert.ToInt32(problem.Y) == y))
        {
            return ErrorColour;
        }

        return y % 2 == 0 ? AlternatingColour : DefaultColour;
    }
}
```